# In Perl, how can I find the index of a given value in an array?

Tags: perl, arrays

```
$VAR1 = [
          '830974',
          '722065',
          '722046',
          '716963'
        ];
```

How can I calculate the array index for the value "722065"?

Comment: Just look for it with a for loop. What if there's two values in the array that are equal?

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Is this homework?

Comment: @jsoverson: I'm new to perl. Self-learning project.

Comment: Since Perl 5.10, you can also use `my ($index) = grep { $array[$_] ~~ $element } 0 .. $#array;`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3222653/111036

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `firstidx` function from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils) can help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(firstidx);

my @nums = ( '830974', '722065', '722046', '716963' );
printf "item with index %i in list is 722065\n", firstidx { $_ eq '722065' } @nums;
```

Outputs:

```
item with index 1 in list is 722065
```

Comment: And if you want to locate multiple such indices, you can use List::MoreUtils::indexes.

Answer (score 26):

using `List::Util`, which is a core module, unlike `List::MoreUtils`, which is not:

```
use List::Util qw(first);

my @nums = ( '830974', '722065', '722046', '716963' );
my $index = first { $nums[$_] eq '722065' } 0..$#nums;
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is how you would find all the positions at which a given value appears:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @x = ( 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1 );
my @i = grep { $x[$_] == 3 } 0 .. $#x;
print "@i\n";
```

If you only need the first index, you should use [List::MoreUtils::first_index](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#first_index-BLOCK-LIST).

Comment: Honestly. Lose the mention of $[. It's obscure, IIRC deprecated and there is no honest reason to use it.

Comment: That's Perl street cred material, thought :-)

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to look up the one item, use `firstidx` as others have said.

If you need to do many lookups, build an index.

If your array items are unique, building an index is quite simple.  But it's not much more difficult to build one that handles duplicate items.  Examples of both follow:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

# Index an array with unique elements.
my @var_uniq  = qw( 830974 722065 722046 716963 );
my %index_uniq  = map { $var_uniq[$_] => $_ } 0..$#var_uniq;

# You could use hash slice assinment instead of map:
# my %index_uniq;
# @index_uniq{ @var_uniq } = 0..$#var_uniq

my $uniq_index_of_722065   = $index_uniq{722065};
print "Uniq 72665 at: $uniq_index_of_722065\n";
print Dumper \%index_uniq;

# Index an array with repeated elements.
my @var_dupes = qw( 830974 722065 830974 830974 722046 716963 722065 );
my %index_dupes;
for( 0..$#var_dupes ) {
    my $item = $var_dupes[$_];

    # have item in index?
    if( $index_dupes{$item} ) {
        # Add to array of indexes
        push @{$index_dupes{$item}}, $_;
    }
    else {
        # Add array ref with index to hash.
        $index_dupes{$item} = [$_];
    }
}

# Dereference array ref for assignment:
my @dupe_indexes_of_722065 = @{ $index_dupes{722065} };

print "Dupes 722065 at: @dupe_indexes_of_722065\n";
print Dumper \%index_dupes;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's hastily written attempt at a reverse look-up using a hash.

```
my $VAR1 = [ '830974', '722065', '722046', '716963' ];

my %reverse;
$reverse{$VAR1->[$_]} = $_ for 0 .. @$VAR1 - 1;

print $reverse{722065};
```

This does not account for arrays with duplicate values. I do not endorse this solution for production code.

Comment: In the case of duplicate values you'll just get the first element that matches. This can be really useful if a long-lived array is queried more than once.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the comment above, but the way the code is written, in the case of duplicate values, the highest index wins.

Answer (score 1):

check out the [Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-find-the-first-array-element-for-which-a-condition-is-true%3F)

Comment: RRTFM-ing (Re-reading the fine manual) is an amazingly rewarding experience.  The first time I read the docs, much of it went right over my head.  Each subsequent reading has revealed new meaning.  It's amazing the number of things you can learn by (re)reading the manual!

Comment: I'd be satisfied if most people at least read it once. People constantly ask how relevant the FAQ is, and StackOverflow has been a great natural experiment: everyone re-asks the FAQ questions.

Comment: @daotoad: maybe that's because I keep changing the FAQ on you. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

sub invert
{
 my $i=0;
 map { $i++ => $_ } @_;
}

my @a = ('a','b','c','d','e');

print Dumper @a;

print Dumper invert @a;
```

Comment: use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
sub mirror
{
 my $i=0;
 map { $i++ => \$_ } @{ shift @_ };
}
my @a = ('a','b','c','d','e');
my %b = mirror \@a;
print Dumper @a;
print Dumper %b;
$a[1] = 'whoa...';
print Dumper @a;
print Dumper %b;
$a[3] = 'IKNOWRIGHT!';
print Dumper @a;
print Dumper %b;