# How to get the index of an element in an array?

Tags: perl

Does Perl have a build-in function to get the index of an element in an array? Or I need write such a function by myself? [ equivalent to PHP array_search() or JavaScript array.indexOf() ]

Comment: What's in the array? Searching an array is a red flag that causes me to evaluate whether I could be using a better data structure. Remember: *hashes* are for searching!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915746/in-perl-how-can-i-find-the-index-of-a-given-value-in-an-array

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
use List::Util qw(first);
$idx = first { $array[$_] eq 'whatever' } 0..$#array;
```

(List::Util is core)

or

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(firstidx);
$idx = firstidx { $_ eq 'whatever' } @array;
```

(List::MoreUtils is on CPAN)

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, 9 times out of 10.

Comment: Why is this better than your solution, Zaid?

Comment: @masonk : Backwards-compatibility for one. Also, `first` will exit the implicit loop upon finding the index that matches. The `grep` equivalent would be `$idx = grep { $array[$_] eq 'whatever' and last } 0 .. $#array;`, a bit hairy for my liking. And then it's miles ahead in the speed-race, when run as `List::Util::XS`.

Comment: Just realized you can't `last` out of `grep` cleanly. Whoops!

Answer (score 15):

Here's a post-5.10 way to do it, with the added benefit of determining how many indexes match the given value.

```
my @matches = grep { $array[$_] ~~ $element } 0 .. $#array;
```

If all elements are guaranteed to be unique, or just the first index is of interest:

```
my ($index) = grep { $array[$_] ~~ $element } 0 .. $#array;
```

Comment: That answer does not fit the question. The index is what goes into the square brackets for array access, so: a number between `0` and `$#array`.

Comment: @daxim : Aren't we after the index of the match(es) here?

Comment: Actually, the answer does fit the question, and very nicely.

Comment: @Alexander : `~~` is the [smart match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail). Think of it as an operator that is smart enough to figure out what you want based on the LHS/RHS data types.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an [`autobox`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/autobox-Core/) solution:

```
use autobox::Core;

my @things = qw/blue black green red green yellow/;

my $first_green = @things->first_index( sub{ $_[0] eq 'green' } ); # code block
my $last_green  = @things->last_index ( qr/^green$/ );             # or regex

say $first_green;    # => 2
say $last_green;     # => 4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write a function for this:

```
sub array_search {
    my ($arr, $elem) = @_;
    my $idx;
    for my $i (0..$#$arr) {
        if ($arr->[$i] eq $elem) {
            $idx = $i;
            last;
        }
    }
    return $idx;            
}
```

The index of the first matching element will be returned, or `undef`.

Comment: My final solution:

    sub array_search {
      my ($element, @array) = @_;
 
      foreach (0..$#array) {
        if ($array[$_] eq $element) {
          return $_;
        }
      }
 
      return -1; 
    }