# In Perl, how can I find the last defined element in an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop, conditional-statements, defined

Using Perl, I wish to find the last element **that is defined** in an array.

So far I have the following:

```
#generating array
$array[100] = (undef);
$array[$columns[1]-1] = $columns [2];

#finding the last element that is defined
for ($i=100; $i>=0; $i--) {
    if (($array[$i] != undef) && (!defined($lastdef)) ){
        $lastdef=$i;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is not working. Any suggestions to improve, using Perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start from 99 as 100 elements array has indexes: 0 .. 99. And break the loop as soon as you find the element:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = (1, 2, undef);

my $lastdef;
for (my $i = $#array; $i>=0; $i--) {
    if (defined($array[$i])){
        $lastdef=$i;
        last;
    }
}

print $lastdef;
```

prints: 1

Comment: Use [List::MoreUtils::last_index](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils).

Comment: @SinanÜnür Yes, it's a generalized function of mine. Instead of `defined()` condition, they allow to use any condition.

Comment: Except that you get C performance with `List::MoreUtils::last_index` See http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ADAMK/List-MoreUtils-0.33/MoreUtils.xs

Comment: @SinanÜnür Yup, see it.

Answer (score 10):

> I'm not sure why this is not working. Any suggestions to improve, using Perl?

The reason you don't know why it is not working is because you are not using

```
use warnings;
```

If you had, you would have been told:

```
Use of uninitialized value in numeric ne (!=) at ...
```

Because `!=` is the [numeric inequality operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators), and it will convert its parameters to numbers. If you do not have `warnings` turned on, this will silently convert `undef` to `0`. Needless to say, having `warnings` turned on is a very good thing, so that you do not make mistakes like this.

It is this line:

```
if (($array[$i] != undef) ...
```

That should be

```
if ((defined($array[$i]) ...
```

Because it is the `defined` function that checks a value for definedness. It is an odd mistake to make, since you even use that same function on the same line.

Also, you can make this simpler by doing

```
if (defined($array[$i])) {
     $lastdef = $i;
     last;
}
```

`last` will here end the loop when the first undefined value is found.

You should also know that you can use a non-hardcoded max value on your loop condition:

```
for (my $i = $#array; $i >= 0; $i--) {
```

`$#array` contains the number of the highest existing index in your array.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I was using {use warnings;} but also {no warnings qw(uninitialized);} in order to avoid printing "Use of uninitialized value within @intronAbundance in concatenation (.) or string at " since I knew some values were undefined... I should have removed it when fixing the script. Also I had tried defined($array[$i]) - my mistake was to forget to end the loop. Thank you again for taking the time to explain line by line.

Comment: Turning off warnings is seldom needed, and always a bad idea.

Comment: Optionally, the `for` loop can be: `for my $i ( reverse 0 .. $#array ){`

Comment: @shawnhcorey what if the size of the array is `1_000_000`?

Comment: Will the array itself fit into memory?

Answer (score 3):

You could be more concise by using a [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) function.  This will find the last element in the array that is defined, but not the index of it.  To find the index of it, you can do something similar to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489764/1114966)** answer using `defined` instead of `eq`.

```
use List::Util qw(first);

my $lastdef = first { defined($_) } reverse @array;
```

Comment: Instead of doubling memory requirements by reversing `@array`, you should have used [List::MoreUtils::last_index](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils).

Comment: @SinanÜnür That's not core though, so I didn't want to assume the user would go to the CPAN. No reason to down vote a working answer for an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a little ugly and obscure (compared to [@TLP's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17899908/100754)), but it was fun to write:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

for my $i (0, 1) {
    my $array = generate_array(8, $i);
    say join ' ', map $_ // '_', @$array;
    say index_of_last_defined_element($array);
}

sub index_of_last_defined_element {
    my $x = $#{ $_[0] };
    my $v = $_[0]->[$x];
    return $x if defined($v) or $x < $[;
    $#{ $_[0] } -= 1;
    goto &index_of_last_defined_element;
}

sub generate_array {
    my $size = shift;
    my $array = [ (undef) x $size ];
    shift or return $array;
    $array->[rand $#$array] = 'x';
    return $array;
}
```

Output:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
-1
_ _ _ _ _ x _ _
5
```

Of course, this is all a bit silly. You should use [List::MoreUtils::last_index](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::MoreUtils):

```
use feature 'say';
use List::MoreUtils qw(last_index);

for my $i (0, 1) {
    my $array = generate_array(8, $i);
    say join ' ', map $_ // '_', @$array;
    say last_index { defined($_) } @$array;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `$[` deprecated?

Comment: Yes, `$[` is deprecated ... but I like honoring it on occasion ;-)

Comment: Fair enough, also I wasn't trying to fire on you for down voting mine.  I hesitated about having the `last_index` option since it isn't core but as you point out, it is exactly what it is made for.