# How to find location of string in a array ends with %?

Tags: arrays, string, perl

My Problem here is I have a array with some stings

```
EX: $line = { devtmpfs  8234932  144   8234788  1%  /dev }

@temp_arr=split(" ",$line);
```

How to search which string is having sub string '%' and I want to assign that string to a variable

```
ie,  My var1 = 1% (according to above case)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [first](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#%24val-%3D-first-%7B-BLOCK-%7D-%40list) from the [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) module.

```
use List::Util qw(first);

my $line  = q{ devtmpfs  8234932  144   8234788  1%  /dev };
my $found = first { /\%\z/ } split " ", $line;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question.

Does this do the job?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr = qw(foo ba%r baz%);

my $count = 0;

foreach(@arr){
    chomp;
    $count++;
    my $element = ($count -1);
    print "Element number $element contains '%': $_\n" if /%$/;
}
```

This will print `Element number 2 contains '%': baz%`, as in this example that is the only string that ends with a `%`

Answer (score 0):

Using `List::MoreUtils` module. Based from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915838/445221).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(firstidx);

my $line = "devtmpfs  8234932  144   8234788  1%  /dev";
my @temp_arr = split(" ",   $line);
my $i = firstidx { $_ =~ /%$/ } @temp_arr;

printf "String: %s, Index: %i\n", $temp_arr[$i], $i;

__END__
```

Output:

```
String: 1%, Index: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.

`$line = { devtmpfs  8234932  144   8234788  1%  /dev }`

should be

`$line = q{ devtmpfs  8234932  144   8234788  1%  /dev };`

Anyway the solution is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $line = q|devtmpfs  8234932  144   8234788  1%  /dev|;
my @temp_arr = split(" ",$line);
my $var;
foreach (@temp_arr){
    if($_ =~ /%$/){
        $var = $_;
    }
}
print "Result: $var";
```

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/e2fNOf)**

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, extract the percentage using a regular expression:

```
my ($percent) = $line =~ /(\d+%)/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html):

```
my $line  = ' devtmpfs  8234932  144   8234788  1%  /dev ';
my ($found) = grep /\%$/, split ' ', $line;
```

Or using a regular expression if you want to specify a default value or warn if the value isn't found:

```
my $found = $line =~ /(\S*\%)(?!\S)/ ? $1 : warn "Value not found";
```